# Difference between sphere and geodesic sphere and hypersphere

Tags: differential-geometry

I see the Alexandrov theorem wich say that every comapct, without boundary embedded in Euclidien space must be a round sphere.
Can someone explain for me the difference between geodesic sphere rond sphere and hypersphere?
Thank you.

Comment: I thought "hypersphere" just meant going in higher dimensions, i.e. the n-dimensional analogue of a sphere, similar to (hyper)plane or (hyper)cube.

Comment: Thank you fr the answer, the doublt I ave is also about the geodesic sphere and the difference  with the sphere

Comment: "every comapct, without boundary embedded in Euclidien space must be a round sphere" Can you clarify this sentence?

Comment: Sorry for the message. Th Alexandrov theorem is:Let M be a compact hypersurface embedded in the Euclidean
space Rn+1. with constant mean curvature. Then M is a round sphere.

Answer (score 0):

$\textbf{Update}$: In response to what I wrote below, since there isn't literature I could find on the "geodesic sphere", I choose to go with what seemed most natural. Why this definition is natural for me, you can read in the comments below.

The hypersphere is just the $n$-dimensional analogue for an $n$-sphere when $n>3$. The geodesic sphere is the sphere  made from geodesics. This can be different from the standard sphere, which can be a smooth, topological, etc type of embedding i.e there doesn't have to be an isotopy between these other embeddings and the geodesic sphere.

Comment: I've never heard of a "geodesic sphere," other than the popularized "geodesic dome."

Comment: @TedShifrin When I read the question I figured, what else could it mean? and what is the most logical definition for it? The correspondence with the geodesic dome is that it is a linear approximation of the smooth sphere i.e on the geodesic dome, the geodesics are straight lines in the literal sense, due to the fact that it is a polyhedron. And so I guess one could say that the dome is an example of the geodesic sphere when you use a flat metic.